# Why does struts2 doesnt work with generics

Tags: generics, struts2

I'm struggling to make this work but with no luck.

Below is sample code and when I call edit method in the jsp all values are filled, but when I want to save changes then get an exception in OGNL.
Maybe stuts2 doesn't work well with generics. Any suggestion would be more than appreciated.

```
public abstract class ActionHelper<T> extends ActionSupport{

    protected T entity;
    protected Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    public void setEntity(T entity){
        this.entity=entity;
    }

    public void getEntity(T entity){
        this.entity=entity;
    }

    public String edit(){
        this.entity=fillEntity();
        return "edit";
    }
    public String save(){
        genericDao.save(entity);

    }
    protected abstract T fillEntity();
}

public class PersonAction extends ActionHelper<Person>{
    Person fillEntity(){
        return genericDao.find(id,Person.class);   
    }
}
```

`<s:form action="person_save" method="post">`
    `<s:hidden name="entity.id">`
    `<s:textfield name="entity.name">`
    `<s:textfield name="entity.surname">`
`</form>`

Comment: can you post the relevant JSP code?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516407/how-to-declare-a-generics-action-in-struts2-xml-file) might be useful.

Comment: +1, Now that I understand this is an interesting issue but if you could change the title to something like "Struts2 and type erasure" , I think people will more clearly understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start tag of the form is: s:form but the end tag is just an html form tag... probably a typo?

You're using a default access specifier for fillEntity and not following java been naming conventions, try this:

```
public Person getEntity(){
    return genericDao.find(id,Person.class);   
}
```

Now OGNL will be able to find "entity" in PersonAction.

Comment: I want to reuse ActionHelper for every ActionEntity where edit/save should be. but I find that Struts 2 can't bind into Person, can't recognize the class.

Comment: Okay I see now.  This isn't a fault of Struts2 it's the way Java works in general.  Type information only exists for the compiler not at run time, this is called "type erasure".  This is the simple story for the more complicated story (and a possible answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509896/getting-around-type-erasure-in-java